# How can I bypass android homescreen lock using voice command to activate an app? Please give me some guidelines to start with

Tags: android, voice-recognition, voice-recording, screen-lock

I want my device to constantly hear for the command(customized, not OK Google) and activate the app when the command matches. All this should be possible even with a locked homescreen.
Please give me some basic idea as to what should I start refering as I am a novice Android developer.

Comment: Is this even possible with all the security features on there? I think the lock screen is intended to "lock" the phone.

Comment: We can activate the apps using buttons even when the screen is locked.The above mentioned thing won't unlock the phone just trigger a specific application to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can archive that with Pocketsphinx on Android. See for details

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid

Even when the screen is locked the recognition for the keyphrase is still running. You can execute your own code in onPartialResult callback once keyphrase is detected.

Comment: Thanks.  I will look through it :)